# how to read or write colormap of a gif image with apple API?

Tags: macos, image, gif

I want to read the color map of a gif image with apple's api and rewrite it.But the followed code doesn't work.I don't know why?

```
for(int i = 0;i < count; i ++){
    const uint8_t colorTable[9] = { 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 255,255,255 };
    NSData* colorTableData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: colorTable length:9];
    NSMutableDictionary *frameProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
    [frameProperties setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:frameDelay] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime];
    [frameProperties setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: 0.1] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime];
    [frameProperties setObject:colorTableData forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFImageColorMap];

    NSDictionary *gifFrameProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:frameProperties forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];
    CGImageRef originImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(sourceImageSrc, i, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(Destination, originImage, (__bridge     CFDictionaryRef)gifFrameProperties);
}
```

Comment: I have used such code ```NSData *frameColorMap = [[frameInfo objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFImageColorMap] objectValue];``` to read the colormap, but the return is nil

Comment: What is the Swift tag for?

Comment: My fault, i have deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.The gif have a global color-map for whole file and a local color-map for every frame in the gif.If you want to set the local color-map, please disable the global color-map.The code is as follows:

```cpp
[frameProperties setObject:targetColorMap forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFImageColorMap];
[frameProperties setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFHasGlobalColorMap];
```